# How to securely write a Joomla SELECT query with an IN condition in the WHERE clause?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla3.0, query-builder, where-in

With a regular MySQL command, we use `SELECT foo WHERE bar IN (a,b,c)`.

How is this properly executed using Joomla's query building methods?

I tried this:

```
$query
    ->select(array('a.id', 'a.promo', 'a.harga', 'a.dp', 'a.image', 'a.teaser' , 'b.title','b.created'))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__cck_store_form_paket_trip', 'a'))
    ->join('LEFT', $db->quoteName('#__content', 'b') . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('a.id') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('b.id') . ')')
    ->where($db->quoteName('b.catid') . ' IN '.$db->quote(.'(13,14,15)'.)
    ->order($db->quoteName($orderby) . ' '.$order)
    ->setLimit($limit,$start)
    ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$db->quote function accepts a value or an array. You can try below code with implode function -

instead of this -

```
$db->quote(.'(13,14,15)'.)
```

Try this -

```
$db->quote(array(13,14,15))
```

and final query will be -

```
$query
    ->select(array('a.id', 'a.promo', 'a.harga', 'a.dp', 'a.image', 'a.teaser' , 'b.title','b.created'))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__cck_store_form_paket_trip', 'a'))
    ->join('LEFT', $db->quoteName('#__content', 'b') . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('a.id') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('b.id') . ')')
    ->where($db->quoteName('b.catid') . ' IN (' . implode(',', $db->quote(array(13,14,15))) . ')' )
    ->order($db->quoteName($orderby) . ' '.$order)
    ->setLimit($limit,$start)
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the static values in your `IN` condition is completely useless in terms of "stability" and "security".  Those data points are not injection attack vectors because are static.  Your query is not at risk of breaking because you have correctly written the integer values.  Quoting the array values is only adding unnecessary code-bloat, causing a slight decrease in efficiency, and making your code harder to read.

See my very comprehensive answer on Joomla Stack Exchange's [How to Use IN Clause in Joomla Query](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/22898/12352).

Instead, your query can be safely/securely written as:

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
    ->select(["id", "a.promo", "a.harga", "a.dp", "a.image", "a.teaser", "a.title", "a.created"])
    ->from("#__cck_store_form_paket_trip a")
    ->innerJoin("#__content b USING (id)")
    ->where("b.catid IN (13,14,15)")
    ->order($db->qn($orderby) . ($order == "DESC" ? " DESC" : ''))
    ->setLimit($limit, $start);
```

Explanation:

- the `select()` method doesn't contain any MySQL keywords or monkeywrenching characters, so none of those static values need to be quoted/escaped.
- the `from()` method doesn't need `qn()` for the same reason.
- instead of long-hand `join('LEFT',...)` syntax, use Joomla's slightly shorter `leftJoin()`.  Better yet, because your WHERE requirements disqualify any `a` rows that join to `null` rows in `b`, it is more appropriate to use `innerJoin()`.
- because the column to be joined on in both tables have identical names, you can enjoy the sweeter syntax of `USING`.  This also means that you won't need to nominate the table alias when referencing `id` elsewhere in the query.
- the `where()` method, as mentioned at the start of my post can be statically written.  Even if you pass in an array that YOU statically wrote earlier in the script, you can safely use it like:

  ```
  ->where("b.catid IN (" . implode(',', $arrayOfIntegers) . ")")
  ```
- because it is safe to assume that `$orderby` is derived from user input, you should continue to implement `qn()` in the `order()` method.  Because `ASC` is the default sorting direction, I only conditionally write `DESC` into my queries (IOW, if the sorting direction is ASC, just omit it).
- the `setLimit()` is fine the way you have it, because the method is hardcoded to cast the passed in values as integers by Joomla.

If you want to see your generated sql query, use:

```
echo $query->dump();
```

To run a basic diagnostic check, you could use the following, **BUT never show the `$query->dump()` or the raw `$e->getMessage()` strings to the public!**

```
// never show $query->dump() to the public
JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage($query->dump(), 'info');
$db->setQuery($query);
try {
    if (!$result = $db->loadAssocList()) {
        echo "No Qualifying Rows";
    } else {
        echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr><th>", implode("</th><th>", array_keys($result[0])), "</th></tr>";
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                echo "<tr><td>", implode("</td><td>", $row), "</td></tr>";
            }
        echo "</table>";
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // never show getMessage() to the public
    JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage("Query Syntax Error: " . $e->getMessage(), 'error');
}
```